# ngTagsInput- what is run when selecting one of the options displayed by autocomplete?

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, multipleselection

I am working on an AngularJS application, and have a dialog which is used to update what is displayed on one of the widgets on a particular page.

The widget is a table, and I want to allow the user to display different data types/ HTML elements in particular cells of the table.

As it currently stands, the cells will display text, a button, or a 'tag' which is a variable taken from the system, and displayed as a particular element using the [ngTagsInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api#autoComplete) library. As the user types into the text input field, the autocomplete feature displays a list of 'tags' that match what has been typed so far- when the user clicks one of these tags in the list, that is when it is then displayed as a tag in the table widget (if they just type the full name of the tag without selecting it from the autocomplete list, it is just displayed as text).

I have made some changes so that when the first character that the user types is a `:`, the autocomplete list should show a list of the various pages of the application, for which a button linking to that page will be added to the table (i.e. typing `page1` would just show the text "page1" in the table cell, but typing `:`, and selecting 'page1' from the autocomplete list would display a button linking to page1). This functionality currently works as expected,.

I now want to be able to add multiple buttons to a single table cell (assuming that the user inputs the tags into the text field in the dialog in the correct format). The format to do this will be the same as for one button, but with a `;` separating each of the individual buttons- for example, to add buttons for page1 & page2 to the same table cell, the user should just type: `:page1;page2`.

The `autocompleteTagsFilter()` function, which is what displays the list of available tags/ pages based on what the user has typed so for (i.e. filters the list of available options as the user continues typing) is defined with:

```
$scope.autocompleteTagsFilter = function(query) {
    if (query.startsWith(":")) {
        // Split the 'query' search string on ':', to use only the string
        var buttonsQuery = query.substring(1);
        if (!buttonsQuery && lastTagQryKw) {
            buttonsQuery = lastTagQryKw;
        }

        /*check whether the buttonsQuery variable contains a ';' - if it does, split it */
        if(buttonsQuery.includes(';')) {
             //console.log("buttonsQuery includes ; - ", buttonsQuery);
             var btnsToDisplay = buttonsQuery.split(";");
             console.log("btnsToDisplay: ", btnsToDisplay);
         }

          // Declare variables to be used in 'for' loop
          var userPages = pagesPresets;
          var page;
          var result = [];

          // 'For' loop should iterate through the list of user pages,
          // and remove path, so that only the page name is shown
          for (page in userPages) {
              page = userPages[page];
              // If the page key starts with 'buttonsQuery', and its length
              // is greater than 6 (i.e. just 'pages/' shouldn't be displayed)
              // add the page to the list of pages to be displayed.
              if (page.key.startsWith(buttonsQuery) && page.key.length > 6) {
                 result.push(page.key);
                 //console.log("result- after result.push(page.key): ", result);
              } else {
                  //console.log("userPages: ", userPages);
              }
          };

          for (btn in btnsToDisplay) {
              console.log("btn: ", btnsToDisplay[btn]);
              result.push(btnsToDisplay[btn]);
              console.log("button added to result: ", result);

          if (result.length > 0) {
              lastTagQryKw = query;
          }

          // Return the list of pages that match what the user has typed
          //console.log("RESULT (when query.startsWith(':') is true) is: ", result);
          return result;

      // Otherwise, if the user types something that does not start with ':',
      //then it should be a tag- search for tags that match this term
      } else {
          if (!query && lastTagQryKw) {
              query = lastTagQryKw;
          }
          var result = Object.keys(fxTag.getTags()).filter(function(name) {
              return name.indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
          });

          if (result.length > 0) {
          lastTagQryKw = query;
          }

          console.log("RESULT (when query.startsWith(':') is false) is: ", result);
          return result;
      }
  };
```

As I type, if I start typing with a `:`, then the browser console displays a list of pages that I could add a button for:

> RESULT (when query.startsWith(':') is true) is:  (4) ["pages/userpage1", "pages/pagetitle", "pages/userpage2", "pages/auth"]

If I select one of these buttons, that button is correctly added, and when I click the 'Preview' button on the dialog, the dialog closes and the page shows the table with the working button correctly added to the table cell. The console also shows the output:

> tag is only one tag:  {tag: "pages/auth"}

which comes from the function `onAddingTagItem()`

However, if I continue typing, rather than selecting one of the buttons shown by the autocomplete, and type out two buttons, i.e.

```
:pages/userpage1;pages/userpage2
```

then rather than displaying two buttons, the table cell just displays the text, i.e `:pages/userpage1;pages/userpage2`.

and I get the console output:

> value of tags:  (2) [":pages/userpage1", "pages/userpage2"]

The same `onAddingTagItem()` function is called in both cases, only it runs the `if` instead of the `else` when the text entered by the user contains a `;`. This function is defined with:

```
$scope.onAddingTagItem = function(tag) {
    if(tag.tag.includes(";")) {

        var tags = tag.tag.split(";");
        console.log("value of tags: ", tags);
        angular.forEach(tags, function(tag, key) {
            if(tag.startsWith(":")) {
                tag = tag.split(":")[1];
            }
            angular.extend(tag, toTagItemObj(tag));
        })
    } else {
        console.log("tag is only one tag: ", tag);
    }
    return true;
};
```

So, as I understand, it should be returning the tags whether there are one or several of them, because it returns `true` whether the `if` or the `else` is run.

Given that this function always returns `true`, whether it's the `if` or the `else` that has been run, why is it that a button is only displayed when I click an option from the `autocomplete` list, and not when typing out a button in full?

How can I ensure that the text entered will be displayed as a button when it meets the criteria (starts with a `:`), even if it's not selected from the autocomplete list, or enable selection of multiple items from the autocomplete list?

Comment: question is soooo long ! can you phrase it into one  paragraphs?

Comment: Not really... I've included everything that's relevant to the question, and not mentioned anything that's not relevant...